# Raw classpath does not update when adding new classpath container

Tags: eclipse

I am adding classpath container when creating our custom project. Whenever I create first project, followed by another I get error

```
Java Model Exception: Java Model Status [Build path contains duplicate entry: 'ISM_CONTAINER' for project 'p2']
```

I want to avoid this error and so wanted to add a check not add classpath container if it already exists. When I check for classpath entries using

```
IClasspathEntry[] rawClasspath = javaProject.getRawClasspath();
```

I don't see entry for ISM_CONTAINER is the array, but I do see it in project properties and in .classpath file. Why don't I get correct entries in the array?

This is what .classpath looks like

```xml
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="con" path="ISM_CONTAINER"/> <classpathentry exported="true" kind="con" path="APPLICATION_CLASSPATH_CONTAINER"/> <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/> </classpath>
```

Comment: What does the .classpath look like?

Comment: [edit] your question and put the information there